# INFURA: sender account not recognized

Tags: ethereum, truffle, geth

I am trying to deploy my contract but it returns this error

> truffle migrate --network ropsten --reset

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- sender account not recognized.
```

truffle_config.js

```
ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
          return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<PROJECTID>")
      },
      network_id: "*", 
      gas: 4000000,
      from: "0x4e2f89...."
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to app the index of the address to the provider?  HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<PROJECTID>", indexOfYourAddress)

Comment: I don't se any docs about it, where did you read it?

Comment: It's in the HDWalletProvider docs

Comment: it works!!! Thank you !!! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've wrote a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, the HDWalletProvider will use the address of the first
>   address that's generated from the mnemonic. If you pass in a specific
>   index, it'll use that address instead.

So if you are using address that isn't the first address from this mnemonic you should ether specify the address

```
HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "ropsten.infura.io/v3/<PROJECTID>", indexOfYourAddress)
```

or unlock multiple addresses by putting number to the forth parameter

```
HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "ropsten.infura.io/v3/<PROJECTID>",0, numberOfAddresses)
```